# Natural Deduction Problem formula

Tags: combinatorics, logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

We define the size $Size(q)$ of a proposition $q$ as the number of variable occurrences in it, i.e.

\begin{align}         
Size(x) &= 1 \\ 
Size(¬q) &= Size(q) \\
Size(q_1 \text{ op } q_2) &= Size(q_1) + Size(q_2)
\end{align}

Let $P(n,s)$ denote the set of all propositions over $n$ variables that have size at most $s$.

How can we generate the formula to finding $P(n,s)$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I undid someone's edit which changed `op` to `or`. I assume `op` was intended, and represented a general operation. Still, the question is unclear. Do you want a formula for the _number of propositions_ in $P(n,s)$?

Comment: As written, $P(n,s)$ is not well defined because $q, \lnot q, \lnot \lnot q, \lnot \lnot \lnot q \ldots$ all have size $1$

Comment: What do you mean by "generate the formula to finding $P(n,s)$"?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much to do with natural deduction in particular ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I was unsure of the tag. sorry.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco I mean to say how to calculate value of P(n,s)? lets say for n<=5 & s<=5. I could not figure out how to solve.

Comment: @RossMillikan assume only q not negation q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring negation, as asked in the comments, you have $P(n,1)=n$ because that is the number of variables.  Any larger formula consists of two smaller formulas combined with an operator.  Let there be $m$ binary operators.  Then $$P(n,s)=\sum_{i=1}^{s-1}P(n,i)mP(n,s-i)$$